# Change margins programmatically causes ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-layout, classcastexception

I want to adjust the margin of my Layout when hide some elements so I have tried this code

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout;
LinearLayout innerLayout;
public void hideInfoarea(){
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContainer);
    innerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerLayout);
    mainContainer.removeView(infoLayout);

    //adjust margins
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)innerLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 10);
    innerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Initially margins of innerLayout are `10,0,0,100` and in my intention this should change the margins in `10, 0,0,10` after infoLayout remotion, but unfortunately I get the follow error

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
            at com.myapp.test.Myactivity.hideInfoarea(Myactivity.java:371)
            at com.myapp.test.Myactivity.switchBoxStatus(Myactivity.java:360)
            at com.myapp.test.Myactivity.onOptionsItemSelected(Myactivity.java:256)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

innerLayout is a `LinearLayout` in my xml, not a `RelativeLayout`. so I don't understand the cause of the issue

Comment: Can you show where you initialize `mainConsole`? If it is a `RelativeLayout` use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params` instead.

Comment: no It's a LinearLayout

Comment: Does your code still throw the same exception after making the code changes in your last edit?

Comment: Yes, but the Fllo suggestion fixed my issue

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Next time post your xml layout as well to help us see how you are defining these views.

Comment: @dcharms give a look to this related issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650542/change-margins-programmatically-doesnt-work-as-expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read `android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams`. @dcharms is right, you should do:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) innerLayout.getLayoutParams();
```

Because, **the parent view** which contains your `innerLayout` is a `RelativeLayout` not a `LinearLayout`.
Let me know if you succeed.

Comment: so I have to use the parent class to get parameters... thanks!!

Comment: but I get another issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650542/change-margins-programmatically-doesnt-work-as-expected