# Change margins programmatically doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a GUI where Initially margins of `innerLayout` are `0,10,0,100` and in my intention `hideinfoarea()`  should remove the `infoLayout` and change the margins in `0, 10,0,10` and `showInfoarea()` should restore the initial margins and show infoLayout again.

Unfortunately when I set these margins some Layout become not well shown, for example the title is too close to mainLayout, and a piece of image will be covered by infoLayout when I re-enable it.
despite in my test with layout editor the margins are perfect.

In adition when I invoke `showInfoarea()` why the layout margins aren't restored to the original conditions, if I simply reverse the operation of `hideInfoarea()`?

Here my code

```
 RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    LinearLayout innerLayout;

    public void hideInfoarea(){
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContainer);
        innerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerLayout);
        mainContainer.removeView(infoLayout);

        //adjust margins
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) innerLayout.getLayoutParams();  
        params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
        innerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

public void showInfoarea(){
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContainer);
        innerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerLayout);
        mainContainer.addView(infoLayout);

        //adjust margins
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) innerLayout.getLayoutParams();  
        params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 100);
        innerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Here the XML

```
   <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:background="@color/Platinum"
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Sample"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/innerlayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/rectangle"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/background_label_mm"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/infoLayout"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#F3F3F4"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull, as you can read one the [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29): `setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` method use `px` and your layout use `dp`. You have to do a conversion like:

```
// where "dp" is your value dip
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                 (float) dp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());  
// then set your margins
params.setMargins(0, px, 0, px);
```

See this answer: [What is the correct way to specify dimensions in DIP from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238883/what-is-the-correct-way-to-specify-dimensions-in-dip-from-java-code) and the reverse one: [Converting pixels to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp).

Also, you can read another thing one the Reference:

> Sets the margins, in pixels. **A call to requestLayout() needs to be done so that the new margins are taken into account.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to help, you make my day ;) Happy coding bro.